# upload multiple images in php using pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I am intending to upload many images at once into a folder and save their information into a db.

As it stands the code does upload these images into the folder correctly regardless of if I select one or many. However when I select many it does not store the information of the images into the database but only uploads the images into the folder. If I select one image then it stores that image’s info into the db correctly.

Below is my code .

```
<?php
#connect to the db
require_once('db.inc.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }try{       
$query ="INSERT into tish_images(FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE)
VALUES(:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,:FILE_TYPE)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':FILE_NAME'=>$file_name,
':FILE_SIZE'=>$file_size,
':FILE_TYPE'=>$file_type));
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
$desired_dir="image_uploads";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"image_uploads/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="image_uploads/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }


        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $query = "INSERT into tish_images(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
             VALUES(:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,:FILE_TYPE)";
    $stmt  = $con->prepare($query);
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
        if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
            continue;
        }
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            continue;
        }
        try{       
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_NAME', $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_SIZE', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_TYPE', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $desired_dir="image_uploads";

            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            }else{    //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

I can't see too much wrong with that but I've refactored the code around pdo a little so its more readable and you only prepare once now. I've moved the actual move file inside the try block too so you only attempt when no error in db execution (you should check the status of the insert - look at $stmt->errorCode() or $stmt->errorInfo()).

Comment: yes you fixed it I appreciated your help  ,  now I what I want  is  to make these images  to be assigned to person who uploaded them . for instance Ian you logged in and upload these images .so when you login again u will be able to view then alone not another user ? what’s the way forward or idea

Comment: @humphrey - The best thing to do would be to try and write the code for assigning the images to the user yourself. If you get stuck then post another question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: @humphrey - Also if Ian's post solved your initial problem then you should accept it as the correct answer by selecting the 'tick' by his response :) Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @DMK you mean where they say  Was this post useful to you?

Comment: @humphrey - [It should look similar to this](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)

Comment: @humphrey - If your unsure about anything on the site try reading the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) or alternatively the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) they can usually help :)

Comment: @MDK my rep is still low am not alowed to vote up a quetion they want a mininum of 15 rep .Thanks guys a lot

Comment: @humphrey - You don't need rep to accept an answer. You just need to click on the `Tick` which is just underneath the Upvote and Downvote you mentioned.

Comment: @DMK You taught me something now I ticked the answer and you guys please vote for my question if it seems to be relevant to the community .

Comment: @Ian Wood why did you put "$key" in the front and back of the "$file_name" file?

Comment: @Jagr - to ensure a 'unique' filename - just incase. belt and braces but omitting probably not a thang. old code this mind - be sure to improve if you use it.

Comment: I am trying to find an updated file upload using PDO but can't find any.